# Extended ASCII in R

Tags: r

The extended ASCII character for '\xfe' is 'þ'.

However, when I try printing the character, I get:

```
> print('\xfe')
[1] "\376"
```

Is there a way to print 'þ'?

EDIT to add context as requested:

```
> getOption("encoding")
[1] "native.enc"
> l10n_info()
$MBCS
[1] FALSE

$`UTF-8`
[1] FALSE

$`Latin-1`
[1] FALSE

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "C"
```

Comment: For context, please can you edit your question to state your OS, and the output of `getOption("encoding")`, `l10n_info()`, and `Sys.getlocale()`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `'\u00FE'`. Hopefully that isn't different in different locales

Comment: I got the following result:
    [1] "<U+00FE>"

Comment: What does `Sys.getlocale()` give you?  You are on Windows, correct?

Comment: On a Mac: `print('\u00FE') #[1] "þ"`

Comment: Does this help: `x <- "\u00FE"; Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"; x`

Comment: It seems it's really an environment issue for me since none of these are working for me. :( I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue on a Linux machine in a C locale

```
.Platform$OS.type
## [1] "unix"
Sys.getlocale()
## [1] "C"
'\xfe'
## [1] "\376"
```

On a Windows machine, it correctly prints a thorn, even when the locale is `"C"`.

If I change the `LC_CTYPE` part of the locale to something with a UTF-8 suffix, and use the `\u` specification that Scott Chamberlain suggested, I can correctly print a thorn.

```
# Easy test, thorn is a common char: Icelandic
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "is_IS.utf8") 
'\u00FE'
## [1] "þ"

# Harder test, thorn is very rare: English
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_GB.utf8") 
'\u00FE'
## [1] "þ"

# Even harder test, thorn is unused: Arabic
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ar_QA.utf8") 
'\u00FE'
## [1] "þ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the extended ASCII char for "\xfe" is "þ"? I thought it worked this way for either "utf-8" or "latin1", if I'm not wrong.

Anyway, this is how I got the print you asked for:

```
x <- "\xfe"
Encoding(x)
#[1] "latin1"
```

`l10n_info()` will give you your locale charset (in my case, LATIN-1 is locale):

```
l10n_info()
#$MBCS
#[1] FALSE

#$`UTF-8`
#[1] FALSE

#$`Latin-1`
#[1] TRUE

#$codepage
#[1] 1252
```

Since both x and the locale charset are latin1, print() will display correctly the character you want:

```
print(x)
#[1] "þ"
```